# Jinja Flask JS and CSS not loading. static files in static

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I've read multiple posts that static files have to be in the /static/ folder and routed to with `url_to` in the html template. But it's not working. The entire site renders and loads with localhost, but externally viewed it only loads text, no css or js.

Console says `404: http://exmaple.com/static/scripts/my_app.js`
Same applies for any images and css.

**/home/me/my_app/web_dynamic/my_app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from models import storage
import uuid

app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
port = 5000
host = '0.0.0.0'

@app.route('/', strict_slashes=False)
@app.route('/my_app/', strict_slashes=False)
def filters(the_id=None):
    state_objs = storage.all('State').values()
    states = dict([state.name, state] for state in state_objs)
    places = storage.all('Place').values()
    cache_id = uuid.uuid4()

    return render_template('my_app.html',
                           states=states,
                           places=places,
                           cache_id=cache_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=host, port=port)
```

**/home/me/my_app/web_dynamic/temaplates/my_app.html**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/myscript.js') }}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <! --- HTML and JINJA HERE -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you have not pushed your code to production and the js file url is not your localhost url, its production url. Thats why its throwing error. try with hardcoded localhost url or make a config url

Comment: @SumanKalyan Sorry if I’m not understanding you. can you elaborate? I can curl localhost from the server with no problem. The browser loads the html just not the script or any images or style sheets.